# Can't use variable in array_columns as column name

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple array and I want to use `array_column` but strangely it does not work using a variable as column name.

```
$colors = array(
array( 'RAL' => 'RAL 1000', 'RGB' => '190,189,127', 'HEX' => 'BEBD7F', 
'NAME' => 'Grünbeige' ),
    array( 'RAL' => 'RAL 1001', 'RGB' => '194,176,120', 'HEX' => 'C2B078', 
'NAME' => 'Beige' ),
    );

$column_name = 'hex'; // this comes actually via $_GET['hex'];
```

This does not work:

```
print_r(array_column($colors, ucwords($column_name)));
```

This does work:

```
print_r(array_column($colors, 'HEX'));
```

Comment: Seems to work with typos (`$column_name` vs `$colum_name`, `array_collumns` vs. `array_column`) corrected. https://3v4l.org/B7qaT

Comment: despite the typos, the problem stays the same. In my real code it's without typos.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example? As can be seen in demo they both work the same. If `array_collumn` is not the native `array_column` function can you please add that definition? https://3v4l.org/EuOfb

Comment: I've updated the sample.

Comment: Ucwords is not the same as strtoupper. Read the manual what ucwords does

Comment: oh my. Of course. Thanks mate!

Comment: In the future, make sure you include all functions you are using in your post. You went too minimal in the first posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use ucwords. That camelcase the word to `Hex`.
Use strtoupper.

```
print_r(array_column($colors, strtoupper($column_name)));
```

https://3v4l.org/c6cum